# Unsigned kernel and Secure Boot

Tags: kernel, touchpad, lenovo, grub-efi, secure-boot

I have just bought a Lenovo Ideapad 330 and installed 18.04LTS. Turns out, touchpad is not working.

I found a solution for the touchpad here: [Lenovo IdeaPad 330 touchpad not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049787/lenovo-ideapad-330-touchpad-not-working)
I then downloaded .deb packages for mainline kernel 4.19 and installed them. Touchpad now working (sort of).

However, I'm concerned about the warnings I got when installing the kernel, about about the kernel being unsigned and thus incompatible with Secure Boot. Also, when installing the package vim-gtk3 I got error messages about shim-signed and grub-efi-amd64-signed.

Is there a way to get rid of these warnings/errors and still have a working touchpad?

And what is this signed/unsigned business about anyway - why are some kernels not signed?

Answer (score 2):

Turn off secure boot in UEFI menu. Every laptop has a different way for doing this, you can find this with a quick google search. This will turn off messages about unsigned kernel and modules.

It only allows signed software to boot.
If you are confident of the downloaded 
Kernel turn it off. Or you can sign it yourself and register machine owner key in secureboot database.

You can read more about Secure Boot [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot&ved=2ahUKEwiY6syO3vTeAhUcTI8KHZeFC7kQFjAAegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw1RYzT3AuGd-S690-JToMKk) & go [here](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2017/08/11/how-to-sign-things-for-secure-boot) if you want to read about signing kernel and kernel modules.

Answer (score 1):

You probably installed an unsigned kernel, that's why Secure Boot complains on it.

Mainline kernels are never signed, but Ubuntu kernels are signed.

You can disable Secure Boot to get rid of those messages.

The Secure Boot feature is not very useful, especially whan you are using a mainline kernel.