# how to install newly generated ubuntu kernel .deb files?

Tags: package-management, kernel, compiling, deb

I tried building ubuntu from the source following BuildYourOwnKernel page.
(https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel
by the way, the page needs some fix now)
I did it on a virtual machine running ubuntu 16.04.6. 
after a long compile time, I see some .deb files like below.

```
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root     4096  2\uc6d4 27  2019 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-45
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root     4096  2\uc6d4 27  2019 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096  4\uc6d4  5  2019 /usr/src/linux-signed-hwe-4.15.0
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096  6\uc6d4 21  2019 /usr/src/linux-meta-4.4.0.179.187
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       45  4\uc6d4 25 04:51 /usr/src/linux-source-4.4.0.tar.bz2 -> linux-source-4.4.0/linux-source-4.4.0.tar.bz2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    18905  4\uc6d4 30 06:38 /usr/src/linux-meta_4.4.0.179.187.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    22259  4\uc6d4 30 06:38 /usr/src/linux-meta_4.4.0.179.187.dsc
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    11648  5\uc6d4 13 05:13 /usr/src/linux-signed-hwe_4.15.0-101.102~16.04.1.tar.xz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     1850  5\uc6d4 13 05:13 /usr/src/linux-signed-hwe_4.15.0-101.102~16.04.1.dsc
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root     4096  6\uc6d4  1 17:06 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-179
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root     4096  6\uc6d4  1 17:07 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-179-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 10591540  6\uc6d4  1 17:44 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-179_4.4.0-179.209_all.deb
drwxr-xr-x 30 root root     4096  6\uc6d4  1 19:33 /usr/src/linux-source-4.4.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  7567320  6\uc6d4  1 19:35 /usr/src/linux-image-unsigned-4.4.0-179-generic_4.4.0-179.209_amd64.deb
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 12564268  6\uc6d4  1 19:36 /usr/src/linux-modules-4.4.0-179-generic_4.4.0-179.209_amd64.deb
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 37074356  6\uc6d4  1 19:36 /usr/src/linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-179-generic_4.4.0-179.209_amd64.deb
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   833524  6\uc6d4  1 19:36 /usr/src/linux-buildinfo-4.4.0-179-generic_4.4.0-179.209_amd64.deb
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1307888  6\uc6d4  1 19:36 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-179-generic_4.4.0-179.209_amd64.deb
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   545846  6\uc6d4  1 19:37 /usr/src/linux-tools-4.4.0-179-generic_4.4.0-179.209_amd64.deb
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   545756  6\uc6d4  1 19:37 /usr/src/linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-179-generic_4.4.0-179.209_amd64.deb
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  3332662  6\uc6d4  1 19:40 /usr/src/linux-tools-4.4.0-179_4.4.0-179.209_amd64.deb
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   561108  6\uc6d4  1 19:40 /usr/src/linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-179_4.4.0-179.209_amd64.deb
```

The files after 19:33 are the generated files.
In what order should I install it?
The BuildYourOwnKernel page shows only three .deb files below and tells me to install other files if there are.

```
linux-headers-4.8.0-17_4.8.0-17.19_all.deb
linux-headers-4.8.0-17-generic_4.8.0-17.19_amd64.deb
linux-image-4.8.0-17-generic_4.8.0-17.19_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install:

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-179_4.4.0-179.209_all.deb
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-179-generic_4.4.0-179.209_amd64.deb
/usr/src/linux-image-unsigned-4.4.0-179-generic_4.4.0-179.209_amd64.deb
/usr/src/linux-modules-4.4.0-179-generic_4.4.0-179.209_amd64.deb
/usr/src/linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-179-generic_4.4.0-179.209_amd64.deb
```

It is an unisgned kernel which might have [issues with secure boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096481/unsigned-kernel-and-secure-boot).

Comment: thanks, I'll test it tomorrow and see if it works. :)

Comment: from your list, the 3rd and 5th seems to be not installed. so I'll try with just the three.

Comment: You might not be able to install an unsigned kernel. I can, and do not know (recall) the details of how to enable, but think it is BIOS setting(s).