# Ubuntu 18.10 doesn't recognize my laptop as laptop

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery, 18.10

I have Lenovo 330-15ich with i5 and gtx1050. But there's one problem. It seems like Ubuntu doesn't recognize my machine as a laptop. I don't have any battery indicator on the top panel, upower -d doesn't show any battery too. What's more, in settings there aren`t almost any options in power configuration. Also laptop doesn't suspend when I close the lid, despite I've chosen this option in Gnome Tweaks. I tried many suggestions from the internet, tried adding acpi=force or acpi_osi=Linux to my Grub configuration file without any results. So I really don't know what to do. Any help would be appreciated)

Comment: Run the command `laptop-detect -v` command (provided by the *laptop-detect* package). If the answer is that your system is NOT recognized as a laptop, then please file a bug report against the 'linux' package. Developers cannot fix what they do not know about.

Comment: `laptop-detect -v` returns `We're a notebook (chassis_type is 10)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found any answer and tried to install elementary OS, which actually runs on kernel 4.15. Everything was great, except one - my laptop didn't suspend on lid close. So I tried to install newer kernel and battery was no more recognized.
**So, the answer is to install old kernel (for me the newest possible was 4.16.18)**. Unfortunately I didn't manage to resolve issue with suspending, looking for solution now. Also I reported it as Linux kernel bug.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear this laptop has many strange hardware IDs that cause the Linux kernel to not understand what hardware it's using:

- [Lenovo IdeaPad 330 touchpad not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049787/lenovo-ideapad-330-touchpad-not-working/)

On most vanilla Ubuntu systems for 18.10 you'll be using a kernel of 4.15 or older, and some are claiming that 4.18+ contain the changes to the Linux kernel to have these hardware IDs detected (note, it's not that Linux is missing the functionality to interface with the hardware, simply that the way the hardware is detected isn't matching various identifiers)

You can try using the *Ubuntu Kernel Update Utility* called `ukuu` to upgrade your kernel to 4.20:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ukuu
```

The run `ukuu` and select 4.20 to install.

More info on [github.com/teejee2008/ukuu](https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu)

Comment: I've successfully installed kernel 4.20, but, unfortunately, the result is the same(