# Touchpad doesn't work on Lenovo ideapad-130-15IKB

Tags: touchpad, lenovo

I recently bought a new Lenovo Ideapad-130-15IKB and installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS alongside Windows. I encountered some issues as soon as I turned my PC on. The touchpad isn't working at all on Ubuntu but is working fine on my Windows 10. I didn't find the device in my `xinput` list:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
    ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ YSPRINGTECH USB OPTICAL MOUSE             id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
        ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ EasyCamera: EasyCamera                    id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I tried to change the kernel version from 4.1k.0-15-generic to 4.18.0-15-generic

but it didn't work unluckily.

From `dmesg | grep i2c` the output is:

```
[    0.917926] i2c /dev entries driver
[   27.763102] i2c_hid i2c-ELAN0620:01: i2c-ELAN0620:01 supply vdd not found, using dummy regulator
```

If there's any solution please post it.

Comment: There is no information to help. And please one problem at a time.

Comment: Sorry i'm a little bit worried about this because i was trying since 4 days all what was proposed but nothing works

Comment: Pilot6 do you have any information about my problem please !

Comment: First of all touchpad and wireless are two different problems. Please remove one issue from your question, otherwise the question may be closed as too broad. You can ask another question regarding the other problem. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: So please add the output of `xinput` to your question. Format it with `{}` button.

Comment: This touchpad is not supported by the 4.15 kernel, but is supported by the 4.18. See this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049787/lenovo-ideapad-330-touchpad-not-working I think the easiest solution will be to install Ubuntu 18.10 that has that kernel by default.

Comment: Changing the kernel version won't change something ?

Comment: Thanks a lot Pilot6 for your help and response

Comment: Another option will be to upgrade kernel to the HWE.

Comment: You have another model of Elan touchpad, `0620`. I'll check if it is supported by any kernel yet.

Comment: It is supported by the 4.20 kernel. You can install a mainline one. I can post a detailed instruction a bit later.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put there the output of `dmesg | grep i2c`.

Comment: If there's any solution please give it to me and thanks a lot Pilot6 for your help

Comment: I'll edit my answer to give a working solution.

Comment: see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a new touchpad model that is not supported by current Ubuntu kernels. The model is `ELAN0620`.

Luckily support has been added to the 4.19 Linux kernel.

I suggest installing a mainline kernel using `UKUU`.

1. Install `UKUU` this way

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install ukuu
   ```
2. Start `UKUU` using GUI, or by running `ukuu-gtk` in a terminal.
3. Choose the latest 4.19 kernel there and press Install.
4. Reboot.

The touchpad should start working.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89789/discussion-on-answer-by-pilot6-touchpad-doesnt-work-on-lenovo-ideapad-130-15ikb).