# How to add support for touchpad elan 0628 in current 19.04 ubuntu

Tags: drivers, touchpad, lenovo, 19.04, elantech

I recently acquired a Lenovo IdeaPad L340-15API that works mostly OK with the exception of the touchpad (and the wireless interface, but I already fixed that). Looking around I found several similar issues for people with other Lenovo laptops, all with ELAN touchpads.

One solution that appeared was [to use an specific kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1118528/touchpad-doesnt-work-on-lenovo-ideapad-130-15ikb), but that is an older version than the one given in Disco. Looking further, it looks like what needs to be done is to patch the kernel [adding this version of the touchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049787/lenovo-ideapad-330-touchpad-not-working) to the drivers/input/mouse/elan_i2c_core.c, and looking at the latest commits on the Linux kernel, this model of touchpad has already been added to de driver, just in a future version of the kernel, [here it is](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/input/mouse/elan_i2c_core.c).

So, how do I add support for this touchpad in the current kernel of Disco?

Output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux twisto-laptop-ultimate 5.0.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 24 09:32:09 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my issue by using [UKTools](https://github.com/usbkey9/uktools) and selecting the latest stable kernel published in mainline, now my touchpad works flawlessly. Output of `uname -r`, which shows the kernel with support for my touchpad:

```
5.0.21-050021-generic
```

What I like about this is that the kernel with support is not too far away, and in the very close future there will be support for this particular elan touchpad.

Answer (score 0):

what you're looking for is [ukuu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/ukuu-easy-way-to-install-mainline-kernel-ubuntu)

install :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt update && sudo apt install ukuu -y && sudo ukuu
```

usage :

[image: ukuu usage]

as per : [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade)

Comment: UKUU isn't available on teejee2008's repository for Disco Dingo. I also tried to compile it from source but the compiler throws me errors. At this point I would like to create the kernel patch with just that extra line and patch my kernel.

Comment: Here is the failed build for AMD64 for Disco in Launchpad https://launchpad.net/~teejee2008/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/16347808

Comment: you know you can just install new kernels like this : `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` after dowloading them from here : https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.2/ ukuu is just a gui tool for this.